# Grand Central Dispatch not showing NSLog statement

Tags: ios, xcode, grand-central-dispatch

I just started using GCD today, and I thought I had an understanding of how it worked, but right now I am a little confused as to why an NSLog statement is not printing / showing in the console.

Basically if I understand GCD correctly there's a couple of steps that need to be done.

1. Create a new queue
2. Add blocks to the queue

Here's an example of how I am using GCD in one of my files,

**ViewControllerWelcome.m**

```
 #import <ViewControllerWelcome.h"
 #import <dispatch/dispatch.h> // Grand Central Dispatch

 @interface ViewControllerWelcome ()
 {
 // declare private methods here
 dispatch_queue_t scan_queue;
 }
 @end

 @implementation ViewControllerWelcome

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];


 // threading stuff - GCD
scan_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.chrisrjones.kegcop", NULL);

// put blocks of code into curly braces to run on separate thread
dispatch_async(scan_queue, ^{

    [serial handShake];
    NSLog(@"execution reached here");

 });
}

@end
```

As it currently operates, I am not seeing the output of the NSLog statement inside the ^{

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on your NSLog statement is it enountered? It's possible `handShake` is not returning

Answer (score 0):

may be your [serial handShake];is blocking..Try to put the log before this call

Comment: i just put NSLog before the [serial handShake] call and it is still not printing this line to the console.

Comment: ok then just put a breakpoint inside the block say on the first statement and run the app, to check everything else is working fine

Comment: it has something to do with the WelcomeViewController being the first ViewController because when I load a different view controller / another view controller my log statements are printed.

Answer (score 0):

Just Try This Way.

```
 NSLog(@"execution reached here");
 [serial handShake];
```

instead of

```
[serial handShake];
NSLog(@"execution reached here");
```